# Changing colors of picture with opencv in c

Tags: image, opencv, colors

I'm trying to write a C program that changes colors of picture and than save it. And it also do this for more than one colors separately. For example, i have picture that has red, blue, purple, and green colors. Program should change all colors to black except red and save picture. Than in original picture, it should change colors to black except blue and save another picture. And than do this for purple and green separately as well. Before saving file, picture would be shown in window.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<time.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

//Files' name and windows' name
char *resim[3] = {"112.png", "116.png", "113.png"};

//b,g,r values; 1-Min, 2-Max, 3-Wil be
int imgB1[] ={150, 190, 0};
int imgB2[] ={220 ,255, 80};
int imgB3[] ={168,190, 66};
int imgG1[] ={100,180, 90};
int imgG2[] ={150,255, 150};
int imgG3[] ={119, 200, 136};
int imgR1[] ={150, 0, 200};
int imgR2[] ={235, 204, 250};
int imgR3[] ={103, 25, 250};

for (int m =0; m<3; m++){

cv::Mat img = cv::imread("62.png",0);

for(int i = 0; i < img.rows; ++i) {

    for(int j = 0; j < img.cols; ++j) {

        int b=int(img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0]);
        int g=int(img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[1]);
        int r=int(img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[2]);

        int degis=0;

        if(b >= imgB1[m] && b < imgB2[m] && g >= imgG1[m] && g <imgG2[m] && r >= imgR1[m] && r < imgR2[m])
        {
                        img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0] = imgB3[m];                            
                        img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[1] = imgG3[m];                   
                        img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[2] = imgR3[m];    
        }
        else{
                        img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0] = 0;                            
                        img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[1] = 0;                   
                        img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[2] = 0;
        }

    }

}


cv::namedWindow(resim[m]);
imshow(resim[m],img);
cv::waitKey(0);
imwrite(resim[m], img);
}

return 0;
}
```

Program stops. There is only "program has stopped" message in black window. I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: why do you try to reinvent cv::inRange() , only worse ?

Answer (score 1):

@berak
I'm not familiar with opencv. I didn't know inrange.

I rewrite code with inrange. Now it works. I will rearrange it later but i share it if someone needs an example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main()
{

    Mat src =imread("atlas40.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    Mat mask,mask2,mask3,mask4,mask5,mask6,mask7;

    // Min values
    int blueMin =190; 
    int greenMin=180;
    int redMin =0;
    //  Max values
    int blueMax =255; 
    int greenMax=255;
    int redMax =204;


    int blueMin2=0;
    int greenMin2=128;
    int redMin2=0;
    int blueMax2=0;
    int greenMax2=255;
    int redMax2=191;
    int blueMin3=0;
    int greenMin3=8;
    int redMin3=175;
    int blueMax3=92;
    int greenMax3=86;
    int redMax3=205;
    int blueMin4=0;
    int greenMin4=90;
    int redMin4=200;
    int blueMax4=80;
    int greenMax4=150;
    int redMax4=255;
    int blueMin5=190;
    int greenMin5=90;
    int redMin5=230;
    int blueMax5=220;
    int greenMax5=150;
    int redMax5=255;
    int blueMin6=50;
    int greenMin6=0;
    int redMin6=50;
    int blueMax6=255;
    int greenMax6=0;
    int redMax6=255;
    int blueMin7=0;
    int greenMin7=200;
    int redMin7=200;
    int blueMax7=180;
    int greenMax7=255;
    int redMax7=255;

    inRange(src, Scalar(blueMin, greenMin, redMin), Scalar(blueMax, greenMax, redMax), mask);
    inRange(src, Scalar(blueMin2, greenMin2, redMin2), Scalar(blueMax2, greenMax2, redMax2), mask2);
    inRange(src, Scalar(blueMin3, greenMin3, redMin3), Scalar(blueMax3, greenMax3, redMax3), mask3);
    inRange(src, Scalar(blueMin4, greenMin4, redMin4), Scalar(blueMax4, greenMax4, redMax4), mask4);
    inRange(src, Scalar(blueMin5, greenMin5, redMin5), Scalar(blueMax5, greenMax5, redMax5), mask5);
    inRange(src, Scalar(blueMin6, greenMin6, redMin6), Scalar(blueMax6, greenMax6, redMax6), mask6);
    inRange(src, Scalar(blueMin7, greenMin7, redMin7), Scalar(blueMax7, greenMax7, redMax7), mask7);

    imshow("Color 1",mask);
    imshow("Color 2",mask2);
    imshow("Color 3",mask3);
    imshow("Color 4",mask4);
    imshow("Color 5",mask5);
    imshow("Color 6",mask6);
    imshow("Color 7",mask7);

    int k = waitKey();

    imwrite("401.png",mask);
    imwrite("402.png",mask2);
    imwrite("403.png",mask3);
    imwrite("404.png",mask4);
    imwrite("405.png",mask5);
    imwrite("406.png",mask6);
    imwrite("407.png",mask7);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your helps.